# Dealing with multiple integer libraries in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I often get proof terms of the form:

```
Lemma of_nat_gt_0: forall (n: nat),
(Z.of_nat n >=? Int32.unsigned (Int32.repr 0)) = true.
```

The theorem is obviously true (Z of a natural will always be `>= 0`. Similarly, `unsigned` of a `repr` of a `0` will yield `0`.

However, they are just *straight up annoying*, because I need to deal with

1. `Int32` from the `CompCert.Integers` module
2. `Z.of_nat` conversions.

Often, I also have terms from `Pos` and `N` definitions.

Thse proofs involve multiple manual rewrites to juggle into some standard form, and then an `omega` call.

is there some way to "normalize" all of these into a single unified representation?

I understand that this implicitly involves transferring between different rings (eg, `Int32` is `Z/(2^32 - 1)`). It would be nice if there's some way to deal with this, because these are the proofs that get annoyingly long.

Comment: Do you mean `>=?` instead of `<=?`?  Also, you might be interested in the `zify ` tactic used in `lia` / `romega `.

Comment: Indeed, I meant `>=?`, thanks. Ah, so `zify` can convert all the natural numbers stuff, right?
What about the compcert integers? Is there a version of `zify` for them?

Comment: As far as I know, there's no `zify` for compcert things, but you can look at the implementation of `zify` (it's in Ltac), and possibly write a similar tactic for compcert things yourself